# Get a dynamic port for windows FTP

Tags: ruby, windows, powershell, ftp, explorer

I am trying to automate a process that requires logging into an online portal that eventually opens windows explorer with an FTP to the secure server.

The address in explorer is something like: ftp://127.0.0.1:56950/

I need to copy a file from this location to the local machine running the script. The problem is the port changes each time. So for example the next time i run it it might be ftp://127.0.0.1:51432/

I am using Ruby to do most of this as I needed to use selenium and ruby selenium is just amazing. But to sort this issue I am happy to use powershell or anything else.

Does anyone have any ideas how I might go about getting this port number? or any other way I can copy a file from this dynamic address?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does that URL come from? Presumably your online portal eventually redirects to it, in which case you'll need to simulate using the portal using Ruby, perhaps. Also what kind of a monster uses FTP in 2017?

Comment: The online portal downloads an executable which then open explorer

Comment: Everything about that sounds spectacularly ill-advised from a security perspective. If this executable opens a port to accept FTP connections it is possible to enumerate all listening TCP ports and look for when a new one suddenly appears as that's likely to be your target process.